# How to print what files are transformed by babel or babel plugin?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-jest, esmodules

I am writing babel and jest configuration that should transform one of node_modules. At the moment is does not work and I would like to know if the error that I am getting is because the files are not transformed. Unfortunately I didn't yet found a way to log all the files that are being transformed by which plugin/preset.

I am using configuration below.

**jest.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  "transform": {
    "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/some-module"],
}
```

**babelrc.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    "@babel/preset-env",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
  ]
}
```

In the end I am getting error related to one of node_modules not being transformed:

```
  Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /something/node_modules/some-module/theme/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import * as theme from './theme';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```